# SQL Server Express 2012 Installation fails with Could not find the Database Engine startup handle in SQL Server Express 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012-express

I have recently done a fresh installation of my work machine. I installed Windows on drive C: but my Users folder is on drive D:. After trying to install SQL Server 2012 Express, I always got errors that said

> Could not find the Database Engine startup handle in SQL Server Express 2012

So I checked Windows Event Viewer. I noticed that there were several errors:

> Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off.
>
> Windows cannot log you on because your profile cannot be loaded. Check that you are connected to the network, and that your network is functioning correctly.
>
> DETAIL - Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.
>
> Windows cannot copy file \?\D:\Users\Default\ to location \?\D:\Users\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS. This error may be caused by network problems or insufficient security rights.
>
> DETAIL - Access is denied

So I think that the user account which corresponds to SQL Server Express does not have r/w rights to my profile folder on D:.

How do I resolve this? I don't know which user account to add to the folder rights and I don't want to give Everyone the rights.

Comment: What exact profile folder do you append these permissions to?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. It was, in fact, a r/w rights error. I have added following users to my profile folder:

```
IUSR
Local Service
Network
IIS_IUSRS
Service
```

I know I went overkill here but I wanted to be sure without giving everyone access rights. I will disable them one by one and find the right one(s) needed to properly run SQL Server Express 2012.